# Using draft js with html in and html out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I would think this is a very very common request but yet, I can't find anything to help me solve it. I've tried various plugins like `draft-js-import-html` and variations but they never seem to fully work, specially when you add an image or embed a video.

Here's a sample HTML That I would like to use in the editor:

```
var sampleMarkup = '<h1>Hello there</h1>' +
    '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i>, <u>Underline text</u><br/ ><br />' +
    '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>' +
    '<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/elderscrolls/images/6/64/Imga.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110501053300" />' +
    '<p>Hello there</p>' +
    '<div class="responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/POrFPyHGKyw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
```

It has some basic `h1`, `bold`, ... as well as an image and an iframe and an iframe with a wrapper to make the video responsive.

What I would like is to have a `draft-js` editor where I can put HTML in (like above) and on change gives me back HTML.

**So if I start with this, how can I give it HTML and get HTML back?**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js'

var sampleMarkup = '<h1>Hello there</h1>' +
    '<b>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i>, <u>Underline text</u><br/ ><br />' +
    '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>' +
    '<img src="./someImg.png" />' +
    '<p>Hello there</p>' +
    '<div class="responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube/link/here" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';

class MyEditor extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        html: PropTypes.string,
        onChange: PropTypes.func
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // TODO: Convert HTML to state somehow using props.html
        this.state = {
            editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(html);
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Editor 
                editorState={this.state.editor}
                onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                     />
        );
    }    
    _onChange(editorState){
        this.setState({editorState: editorState});
        // Convert state to html somehow here
        this.props.onChange(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solved it somehow? I'm having the same issue. I want to deal with html only..

Answer (score 0):

For different versions of the `draft.js` is different, here is the option for `draft.js 0.10.0`.
For normal output, for example images need to describe to the editor in each case. This is done using `CompositeDecorator`.
Here is an example of github `draft.js`

https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/convertFromHTML/convert.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [draftjs-to-html](https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-to-html).

```
import { convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

const rawContentState = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());

const markup = draftToHtml(
  contentState, 
  hashtagConfig, 
  directional, 
  customEntityTransform
);
```